# If $y''(x) +1 = 1/y(x)$ and $y(0)>y'(0)=0$, then for what $L$ does $y(0)=y(L)$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, periodic-functions

All functions $y(x)$ that satisfy $$y''(x) +1 = \frac{1}{y(x)},\quad y(0)>y'(0)=0$$ seem to have a period $L$ such that $y(L)=y(0)$. Can this be proven, and more importantly, can one calculate $L$ in terms of $y(0)$?

Comment: The question is interesting. Nevertheless, if you don't provide context, your thoughts on the problem and what you've attempted so far, the question will be closed and deleted.

Answer (score 4):

Multiply with $y'$, integrate to get the energy function
$$
E=\frac12y'^2+y-\ln|y|
$$
This is a convex function over the half-plane $y>0$. It has compact level sets without further stationary points except the center at $(y,y')=(1,0)$. The solutions thus rotate along the level curves, the solutions are periodic.

Comment: This is a very simple and nice argument, thank you! Is there any way to use the energy functional to calculate the period $L$ in terms of $y(0)$?

Comment: No, not really. You can formally write down an expression using separation of variables so that $L/2=\int_a^bdy/\sqrt{2(E-y+\ln y)}$ where $a,b$ are the points with $y'=0$, $ae^{-a}=be^{-b}$.

Answer (score 1):

I will suppose, without proof, that there is a finite solution $y$ to the equation. In this case, the continuity of the derivative $y'$ is clear by integration.

We first prove that $y$ must have a turning point. By contradiction, suppose $y$ doesn't have a turning point. Suppose further that there is an $\epsilon<1$ and an $x_0$ such that $y\leq \epsilon$ for all $x\geq x_0$. Then,
$$y''\geq\frac{1}{\epsilon}-1>0$$

for all $x\geq x_0$, and so $y$ would become arbitrarally large, a contradiction of $y\leq 1$. Thus, there is a point $x_1>x_0$ and an $M>1$ such that $y\geq M$ for all $x\geq x_1$. But in this case,

$$y''\leq \frac{1}{M}-1<0$$

So $y'$ would have to eventually cross zero, a contradiction of $y$ not having a turning point. Thus, $y$ must have a turning point.

Now note that our original equation is space-reversal invariant,

$$y''(-x)+1=\frac{1}{y(-x)}$$

Thus, let $\tfrac{L}{2}$ be the first positive turning point of $y$. Then $y(\tfrac{L}{2}-x)=y(\tfrac{L}{2}+x)$ for $0\leq x\leq \tfrac{L}{2}$. Thus $y(L)=y(0)$. Inductively applying this argument shows that $y$ has periodicity $L$.